# Improve Three.js performance with SSR (Node,js next,js)

Tags: three.js, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to find best solution to improve my website with three.js performance.

I would like to ask someone who have tried three.js with Server Side Rendering and if the

performance improve.

My three.js project include 5 glb files in the scene. Each file is about 1MB.

So far I improved.

1. Speed Index First
2. Meaningful Paint

by using webpack

** minify and include all javascript into one file.

** use next generation image wep for all textures.

** able gzip to my sever

Also, to improve loading speed instead of load all 5 glb models at the beginning,
load it 1 or two first, then load rest of models when user needed.

To reduce fan sound( the CPU cause)

I did animate render only user interact

```
  window.addEventListener("wheel", function(e) {

                  animate();
     }, true);
```

```js
var scene, renderer, camera, model, mixer;
function init() {
  var container = document.getElementById( 'container' );
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 30, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
  camera.position.set( 1, 2, - 3 );
  camera.lookAt( 0, 1, 0 );
  clock = new THREE.Clock();
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xa0a0a0 );
  scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0xa0a0a0, 10, 50 );

var hemiLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xffffff, 'rgb(100,100,100)' );
hemiLight.position.set( 0, 20, 0 );
scene.add( hemiLight );
        
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 2000, 2000 ), new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0x999999, depthWrite: false } ) );
mesh.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;
mesh.receiveShadow = true;
scene.add( mesh );
var grid = new THREE.GridHelper( 2000, 20, 0x000000, 0x000000 );
grid.material.opacity = 0.2;
grid.material.transparent = true;
scene.add( grid );
        
var textload = new THREE.TextureLoader();
var text = textload.load( require('./material/text.jpg') );
//text.jpg = 80kb;
text.flipY = false;
          
var textloadbbump = new THREE.TextureLoader();
var textbump = textloadbbump.load( require('./material/textbump.jpg') );
//textbump.jpg = 50kb;

textbump.flipY = false;
                        
var loader = new GLTFLoader();
//character.glb is 1.1MB    
loader.load( require('./material/character.glb'), function ( gltf ) {
    model = gltf.scene;
model.traverse( function ( child ) {
if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
child.material.roughness = 1;
if(child.name=='body'){ 
  
child.material.map = text;
child.material.bumpMap = textbump;
child.material.bumpScale = 0.001;

}
}});
              
              
scene.add( model );
   mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( model );
   mixer.clipAction( gltf.animations[ 0 ] ).play();

  });
  

              renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { 
                  //    antialias: true
                      powerPreference:   'low-power',
                      //precision: 'lowp'
                  } );
  renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
  renderer.shadowMap.enabled = false;
  container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
 
          
          
      }
window.onresize = function () {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
};


init();

window.addEventListener("wheel", function(e) {
requestAnimationFrame( animate );
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
         }, true);
```

Comment: Hard to help you without seeing some of your code or files. But my first guess at what might be causing a problem is the complexity of your models. 5MB worth of 3d is a lot of triangles to be rendering. That said, it would also be causing slow download. why are your 3d files so large? Do they need to be so large?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your replay. I added my code as well. 
I created 3d model file with very low polygon and 1MB minimum file size that I can create my 3d character model. 
I assumed that there is no more option that I can improve my script but since I usually working in Apache/PHP/Mysql environment, if using server side rendering node.js/next.js/react improve my performance as well.

Comment: Do you render in `animate()`? Then one thing for sure you shouldn't render on wheel event.  Mouse event emits much faster than animation frame. Call render function on [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) instead.